# Risks of replacing SOQL query with QueryLocator

Tags: dynamic-soql, querylocator

I used to have this block of code in a widely used method:

```
SObject[] ls = Database.query(q);

SObject[] children = new SObject[]{};
for (SObject l : ls)
{
    for (SObject c : l.getSObjects('Children__r')) children.add(c);
}
```

This started giving errors with large data sets, so I switched to using a `QueryLocator` instead:

```
Database.QueryLocator locator = Database.getQueryLocator(q);
Database.QueryLocatorIterator it = locator.iterator();

SObject[] children = new SObject[]{};
while (it.hasNext())
{
    SObject l = it.next();
    for (SObject c : l.getSObjects('Children__r')) children.add(c);
}
```

I know that there are limitations on the number of active iterators, but besides that are there any risks that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 4):

There's no "risk" with using QueryLocator as compared to using a direct assignent. Your code would use (about) same amount of CPU time, but may use less overall memory, and has a reduced chance of expired cursors. Note that using the following construct is more CPU friendly; whenever you put a query in a loop directly, you automatically get a QueryLocator:

```
SObject[] children = new SObject[]{};
for (SObject l : Database.query(q))
{
    for (SObject c : l.getSObjects('Children__r')) children.add(c);
}
```